# Applet does not start

Tags: java, html, applet

I use Applet added to html.
But the picture did not perform.
No error message.
What went wrong?
I use appletviewer to test.
Like what did not.

HTMLCODE

```
<body>
<applet code=SS.class 
        archive="av.jar, httpclient-4.2.2.jar, httpcore-4.2.2.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, fluent-hc-4.2.2 httpclient-cache-4.2.2, httpmime-4.2.2"
   width=719 height=679>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is very confusing
So I just open his framework
I similar framework does not should normal operation

JAVA CODE

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class SS extends Applet
{ 
    /**
     * 
     */
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
    win1 bb = new win1(); 
    } 
} 


class win1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{ 

    JButton bt2 = new JButton("1"); 
    JButton bt3 = new JButton("2"); 
    JButton bt4 = new JButton("3");
    JButton bt5 = new JButton("4");
    JButton bt6 = new JButton("5");
    JButton bt = new JButton("6"); 
    JButton bt7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton bt8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton bt9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton bt10 = new JButton("10");
    JButton sd = new JButton("11");
    JRadioButton jb1=new JRadioButton("12",true);


    private JLabel Jlb_ID = new JLabel("13");
    private JLabel Jlb_PW = new JLabel("14");
    private JLabel txAC = new JLabel("15");
    private JLabel txPW = new JLabel("16");
    private JLabel Jlb_IP = new JLabel("IP");
    private  JTextField jpw = new  JTextField(10);
    private  JTextField UN = new  JTextField(4);
    private  JTextField TM = new  JTextField(2);
    private  JTextField F4 = new  JTextField(1);
    private  JTextField kg = new  JTextField(6);
    private  JTextField jid = new  JTextField(10);
    private  JTextField name = new  JTextField(10);
    private  JTextField pass= new  JTextField(10);
    private  JTextField ip= new  JTextField(10);

    public win1() 
    { 
        super("win"); 
        setSize(100,800); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setVisible(true); 



            Container pn = getContentPane();
            FlowLayout fy = new FlowLayout();
            pn.setLayout(fy); 
            bt2.addActionListener(this);  
            bt3.addActionListener(this);
            bt.addActionListener(this);
            bt4.addActionListener(this); 
            bt5.addActionListener(this);
            bt6.addActionListener(this);
            bt7.addActionListener(this);
            bt8.addActionListener(this);
            bt9.addActionListener(this);
            bt10.addActionListener(this);
            sd.addActionListener(this);
            jb1.addActionListener(this);
            pn.add(Jlb_IP); 
            pn.add(ip); 
            pn.add(txAC);
            pn.add(pass);
            pn.add(txPW);
            pn.add(name);
            pn.add(bt2);
            pn.add(Jlb_ID);
            pn.add(jid);
            pn.add(Jlb_PW);
            pn.add(jpw); 
            pn.add(bt); 
            pn.add(UN); 
            pn.add(bt7);
            pn.add(bt8);
            pn.add(TM);
            pn.add(bt9);
            pn.add(bt3);
            pn.add(bt4);
            pn.add(bt5);
            pn.add(bt6);
            pn.add(F4);
            pn.add(bt10);
            pn.add(kg);
            pn.add(sd);
            pn.add(jb1);


            Jlb_PW.setLocation(250,50);
            Jlb_PW.setSize(100,20);
            Jlb_PW.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16)); 
            txPW.setLocation(250,50);
            txPW.setSize(100,20);
            txPW.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16)); 
            bt2.setLocation(250,50);
            bt2.setSize(100,20);
            txPW.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16)); 
            txAC.setLocation(250,50);
            txAC.setSize(100,20);
            txAC.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16)); 
            Jlb_ID.setLocation(100,200);
            Jlb_ID.setSize(100,20);
            Jlb_ID.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
            jpw.setLocation(70,50);
            jpw.setSize(100,20);
            jpw.setToolTipText("KKKKK"); 
            jid.setLocation(10,50);
            jid.setSize(100,20);
            jid.setToolTipText("KKKKKK");
            name.setLocation(10,150);
            name.setSize(100,20);
            pass.setLocation(10,200);
            pass.setSize(100,20);
            ip.setLocation(10,250);
            ip.setSize(100,20);

            setContentPane(pn);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 



   }
```

Comment: 1) Don't do either of `setSize(..)` or `setLocation(..)`.  Instead use layouts, padding and borders to layout the GUI.  2) You should have been testing this long before the amount of code in the `SS` class.  Compile/run often!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think rather then creating main in `public class SS extends Applet` you have to  create `init()` method .

```
public class SS extends Applet
 { 
   /**
    * 
    */
   public void init() {
     win1 bb = new win1(); 
     getContentPane().add(bb )
   }
}
```

But First you have to go through basics of applet [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)